# Get selected item after selecting

Tags: java, android

I am able to set the spinner value to the first item on the list. I want to get the value after selecting an item from the list.

Using the [android spinner class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html).

```
package com.example.nddudumaguingbsit.atry;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner sp1;
TextView tv1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sp1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    sp1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
           sp1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                   tv1.setText("ROFL");
               }
           });

            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
```

more info and examples here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html